# execute function after all asynchron functions are executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

How can I achiev to execute a function after three asynchronous functions are executed ? My workaround for this is a global counter.

My problem in detail:
When the save function is called, 3 asynchron webapi calls are made to send the changed data to the server. After that I need to call a function which prints and logs for example, that the save command was successfull.

This is my current workaround. But it seems not to be very nice. And sometimes the counters value is not correct.

```
function save () {
  callwebapi1(parameters, function (dataOnSuccess) { counter = counter - 1; canMethodBeExecuted(); });
  callwebapi2(parameters, function (dataOnSuccess) { counter = counter - 1; canMethodBeExecuted(); });
  callwebapi3(parameters, function (dataOnSuccess) { counter = counter - 1; canMethodBeExecuted(); });
}

function canMethodBeExecuted () {
  if (counter < 0) {
    counter = 3;
    functionToExecuteAfterSaveIsFinished();
  }
}
```

Is there a better solution like the above one?

Comment: `$q.all` is the solution. See documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use promises/deferred in AngularJS:

```
    var promises = [];
    promises.push($http.get('/webAPI1'));
    promises.push($http.get('/webAPI2'));
    promises.push($http.get('/webAPI3'));
    $q.all(promises)
      .then(function (results)
       {
           for (var k = 0; k < results.length; k++) {
                 // iterate through results and do what you want 
           }
       });
```

read [the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

use the angular promise library $q. It will ensure the required actions are completed before performing the next.

```
var save = function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer(),
      counter = 3,
      callback = function () {
        counter --;
        if (counter < 0) deferred.resolve();
  };

  callwebapi1(parameters, callback);
  callwebapi2(parameters, callback);
  callwebapi3(parameters, callback);
  return deferred.promise;
}

save().then(function(){
  //code to run after your calls are complete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `async` [(see here)](https://github.com/caolan/async), in your case the `parallel` method :

```
function asynchronousMethod1 (callback) {
  // ... API call, whatever... then :
  callback(null, 'data1');
}

function asynchronousMethod2 (callback) {
  callback(null, 'data2');
}

function asynchronousMethod3 (callback) {
  callback(null, 'data3');
}

async.parallel([
  asynchronousMethod1,
  asynchronousMethod2,
  asynchronousMethod3
], function (err, results) {
  // results === ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
});
```